# Find the value of a masked CI/CD variable

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am currently trying to find the value of a CI/CD variable in a VM. I tried to output it but I find out the variable’s value is masked in job logs. This is the code I used in my .gitlab-ci.yml.

```
image: python:3

stages:
  - deploy

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "List all CI/CD variables"
    - export
```

The line in question is

```
...     
declare -x Secret_variable ="[MASKED]"
...
```

Is there a way for me to get the find value without modifying the checkbox in the Variables section of Gitlab?

Comment: If you were able to show a masked variable in Gitlab CI logs, that would beat the whole purpose of the variable being *masked*. Masking a variable is done for exactly this purpose, that it's value does not accidentally leak in the logs.

Comment: Those with permission can view the value in the CI/CD setting page. Just click the "reveal values" button.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can reveal the values of CI/CD variables in the settings page for the project (or group, if it is a group variable) by clicking the "reveal values" button.

[image: reveal value button]

You must have [maintainer permission](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html) or higher to do this.

Alternatively, you *can* expose secrets in the job log if you transform the value such that it won't be masked in the job log. This is a bad idea because you'd be exposing sensitive values in plaintext, but it can be done nevertheless.

Unlike other CI platforms, GitLab only masks the *exact* value. For example, you can print the values base64 encoded, print the characters in reverse order, mangle them in any way, etc. and they will not be masked in the job log.

It's also good to know this can happen accidentally, for example, if you use secrets in `curl` as basic auth requests with verbosity enabled, since the verbose logs will show the parameters base64 encoded. `curl -vvv --user "${USERNAME}" --password "${SECRET_PASSWORD}"` will expose your CI/CD variables in the job log, for example.

You can, of course, do this intentionally as well...

```yaml
expose_secrets:
  script:
    - echo $SUPER_SECRET | base64
```

GitLab's security model works around trusted developers. You should obviously not do this unless you have legitimate reason to do this. Doing this can probably get you in trouble a lot of places, unless it's your job to pentest systems, for example. When secrets are exposed in the job log like this, even in base64 form, they should be treated as **compromised** and be rotated immediately.

Comment: And an example that unmasks a variable to a human readable plaintext instead of base64: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61258640/3620458.