# Unmask inherited masked gitlab CI/CD variable

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Does anyone know how to get the value of a [MASKED] variable in Gitlab in one project which inherits this [MASKED] variable from another parent project where I don't have access?

Running the .gitlab-ci.yaml in the CI/CD pipelines in Gitlab gives me :

```
...
$ echo $ENV / $VERSION / $LEANIX_SERVICE_URL 
development / 1.1.0 / [MASKED]
...
```

The settings of the project can be seen in the following screenshot :
[image: project CICD variables screen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have [maintainer or higher privileges](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html#:%7E:text=Manage%20CI/CD%20variables) on the `Biz-IT` group (the group from which that variable is inherited) in order to see the value of the inherited variable. The hyperlink of the group name from your project Ci/CD variables settings will take you to the CI/CD settings page for the `Biz-IT` group, if you have permissions to it. From that page, if you have permission, you can reveal the value.

While it is possible to expose the value in your job (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69789910/find-the-value-of-a-masked-ci-cd-variable/69790515#69790515)) it's not a particularly good idea. The variable is probably masked for a reason -- because the person who created it doesn't want it exposed in job logs. You should strongly consider contacting an administrator or someone in that group with sufficient permissions if possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! That's the thing, the maintainer of the Biz-IT group does not want to give away that variable and I just want to get its value so that I can do the curl command on my private machine instead of going to Gitlab and checking the output of each pipeline after each commit ... So, i'm looking for a command that will allow me to expose the content of that variable instead of getting the output as [MASKED].

Comment: Yes, see [the answer I linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69790515/5747944) for that @R13mus

Comment: So, if I put it in my stage (leanix) and I check it with CI Lint from Gitlab I get the following validation error of .gitlab-ci.yml : "jobs:leanix_sync config contains unknown keys: expose_secrets". If you are saying to put it as a separate stage (i need to add stage: secrets to the code you pointed out and add it to my stages) and there I get an ecrypted output like ('aHR0cHM6Ly9ldS00LmxlYW5peC5uZXQvc2VydmljZXMK').

Comment: @R13mus the output is not encrypted. It's base64 encoded. You can simply run it through a [base64 decoder](https://www.base64decode.org/) Also be aware you just shared your secret in your comment in that base64 string.

Comment: And you are right :) I will mark your answer as correct. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer how to expose the content of this variable. This is the modified content of my ".gitlab-ci.yml file".

#### Solution

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk

stages:
  - dotnet
  - leanix

...

leanix_sync:
  stage: leanix
  variables:
    ENV: "development"
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop"'
      variables:                              
        ENV: "development" 
    ...
  before_script:
    - apt update && apt -y install jq
    - apt-get install -y libxml2-utils  
  script:
    - IFS='/' read -r -a FILES <<< "$LEANIX_SERVICE_URL"
    - echo ${FILES[*]}
```

The idea is to split the initial string by a character that I am sure that I will find inside like '/' and then add the output to an array and obtain the following :

```
$ IFS='/* read -r -a FILES <<< "$LEANIX_SERVICE_URI
$ echo ${FILES[*1}
...leanix.net services
```

#### Not working

**(Actually works, it just gives out an encoded string)**

What I did try and did not work : as indicated by @sytech I tried adding the following to my **.gitlab-ci.yml**.

##### First try:

Editing **.gitlab-ci.yml** :

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk

stages:
  - dotnet
  - secrets
  - leanix

dotnet_sync:
  stage: dotnet
  before_script:
    - export dotn=test1
  script:
    - echo $dotn

expose_secrets:
  stage: secrets
  script:
        - echo $LEANIX_SERVICE_URL | base64
...
```

Give the following encrypted output :

```
360cf9253862953e065035c ...
$ echo $LEANIX_SERVICE_URL | base64
aHR0cHMGLY91dSOOLmxlYWSpeC5uZXQvc2VydmljZXHK
Cleaning up file based variables
Job succeeded
```

##### Second try:

Editing **.gitlab-ci.yml** :

```
leanix_sync:
  stage: leanix
  variables:
    ENV: "development"
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop"'
      variables:                              
        ENV: "development" 
  before_script:
    - apt update && apt -y install jq
    - apt-get install -y libxml2-utils  
  script:
    - echo $LEANIX_SERVICE_URL | base64 
    - cat packages.config
...
```

```
$ echo $LEANIX_SERVICE_URL | base64
aHR0cHMGLY91dSOOLmxlYWSpeC5uZXQvc2VydmljZXHK
$ cat packages. config
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
```

Comment: In the second example, the value is *not* encrypted. It's base64 encoded. Basically plain text, but in another format. Just run the value through a base64 decoder, [like this online one](https://www.base64decode.org/) or using whatever programming tool you prefer. That will get you the exact unaltered value.

Comment: After you decode the base64 value you again need to decode the jwt token to see the human readable token You can use jwt decoder or use https://jwt.io/ for decoding