# Do we need to mask SSH keys in Gitlab runner?

Tags: ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

As you may know Gitlab runner curently cannot mask SSH keys to due [pattern requirements](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/index.html#mask-a-cicd-variable) but there are some [work arounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60247900/gitlab-masking-variables).

My question is, do we even need to mask the SSH keys? It seems Gitlab runner won't even log it unless you explicitly want to.

For example, a common usage of SSH key in `gitlab-ci.yml` is something like this:

`- echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -`

Correct me if I'm wrong, but this command would not really log or show the plain text value of `$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` in the runner's output or logs, right?

Or, if I'm wrong, what places the runner would have logged the plain text value?

Comment: I think the idea here is also related to limiting the number of people who have access to the key. If you have contributors to the project who could push a commit that *does* reveal the value, then masking might be valuable. The point isn’t just to hide it from yourself if you’re already the key owner. But you can find workarounds to the workarounds to reveal the value so ultimately yes you do have to trust your protected branches so pairing masking with limiting the key permissions and the maintainers list are both good ideas.

Comment: See e.g. the unmasking trick here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61258640/3888719